# Straight line forecasat with Statsmodels ARIMA

Tags: machine-learning, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I am new to statsmodels ARIMA
What is the best approach to do ARIMA on such a dataset?

The goal is to forecast the Value of the different types of gas.

I have run Augmented Dickey-Fuller test and have concluded that data is stationary.

How do I get a more accurate forecast?

| Date | T | RH | Gas | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/2/2017 | 6.62 | 51.73 | CO | 845.23 |
| 6/2/2017 | 6.62 | 51.73 | HC | 626.34 |

```py
#Initialising ARIMA model

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

arima_model = ARIMA(scaled_df.Value, order=(2,0,1)).fit()

arima_model.summary()


start = len(df)
end = len(df) + len(test) -1

test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
test.set_index('Date', inplace=True)


pred = arima_model.predict(start=start, end=end,typ='levels')
```

[image: This are the results of the forecast]

Answer (score 0):

i think it might be due to your training data being too large, try splitting it into smaller chunks